# Dynamic queryset into form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form to ask for a title and a list of users. My problem is that I want to display all the users in the database but exclude the current authenticated user. I have tried several options but they were not right. Could you help me? Thank you:

```
from django import forms

class FormCal(forms.Form):

titulo = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

usuarios = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the request object in `__init__` of form class. You can dynamically adjust the queryset there.

```
class FormCal(forms.Form):

    titulo = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(FormCal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # exclude logged in user from queryset
        usuarios_queryset = User.objects.all().exclude(username=self.request.user.username)
        # add field to form
        self.fields['usuarios'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=usuarios_queryset,
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            required=False)
```